# How to scan all javadocs of the Java standard API for the @since tag?

Tags: java, javadoc

I want to make a map of Java versions to classes, their methods and enum values that exist in the standard Java API since those versions. For example the standard class `String` exists since Java 1.0 and the `String::strip()` method exists since Java 11. Both the class and the method have the `@since` tag with the appropriate Java version in their javadocs and this is what I want to scan programmatically.

Maybe there is another way, not related to javadoc? For example since Java 9 the compiler supports the `-release` argument that among other things checks the compatibility of the used APIs with the chosen version of Java release. In case of `-release 10` and a code with `String::strip()` a compilation error is thrown. How does the compiler do it? Does it scan the `src.zip` for javadocs during every compilation or use a smarter technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing `@since` might be error-prone because there are some pitfalls:

- Especially for methods it is inconsistent; for example [`String.startsWith(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) has `@since 1.0` but [`String.endsWith(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) has no `@since` tag
- The value might be unexpected for overridden methods, see [JDK-8254572](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8254572)
- It might be incorrect. The value is not validated in any way so it could happen that it is incorrect, examples for this are: [JDK-6372816](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6372816), [JDK-8164057](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8164057), [JDK-8260561](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8260561)

If you as developer just want to know which new API was added, you can have a look at the ["New" tab](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/new-list.html) of the documentation, added in Java 17 by [JDK-8265055](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8265055) (this is based on the `@since` information).

The `--release` option of `javac` uses the file `lib/ct.sym` from the JDK installation which stores information about the public API of previous versions. See the "Implementation" section of [JEP 247](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/247). There are however some pitfalls with this as well:

- The support for older versions is dropped; for example Java 12 and newer [does not support Java 6](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8206877)
- At the moment it does not include information about [unsupported API](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8206937); most prominently `sun.misc.Unsafe`

There are however third-party tools which allow you to generate or compare the Java API signatures:

- [JDK API Diff Report Generator](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-api-diff)
- [The Java Version Almanac](https://javaalmanac.io/)
- [Animal Sniffer Maven plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/examples/generating-java-signatures.html)